# JavaScript client API for task groups?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-extensions

Most REST APIs of TFS/VSTS have a JavaScript client for extensions to use. Is there one for `/_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups`?

I've poked around the files under https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/tree/master/typings , couldn't find one.

We're on TFS 2017u2.

Comment: Are you looking for this https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/distributedtask/contracts/taskgroupdefinition?

Comment: I'm looking for something like this: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/core/restclient/corehttpclient2_1

Those JavaScript API wrapper classes exist for a large subset of the TFS REST API surface, they're mostly undocumented (but see the linked Github pages), but they're by far more convenient than direct AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but it is still in preview. You can search keyword "taskgroup" in [tfs.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk/blob/master/typings/tfs.d.ts) to get the detailed information.

To use it in your extension:

```
VSS.require(["VSS/Service", "TFS/DistributedTask/TaskAgentRestClient"], function (VSS_Service, TFS_TA_WebApi) {
var taClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_TA_WebApi.TaskAgentHttpClient);
taClient.getTaskGroups("ProjectName").then(
    //...
);
});
```

Remember to add `vso.taskgroups` scope in your extension. I'm not very sure about TFS2017 Update2, but I tested it on TFS2017 Update3, it works.

Comment: `VSS_Service.getCollectionClient()` errors out. You can get a REST client object via `TFS_TA_WebApi.getClient()`, but that object doesn't have a `getTaskGroups` method. I'll revisit once we upgrade our TFS.

Comment: For getCollectionClient? This: Uncaught TypeError: n is not a constructor
    at n.getHttpClient (Service.js:3)
    at Object.k [as getCollectionClient] (Service.js:3)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (main.html:319), <anonymous>:1:5)